# Which tests to run for a population repeatedly measured both before and after a treatment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I have an experiment with 10 environmental plots that will be measured for CO2 output daily for 3 months. At about halfway through the experiment a treatment will occur to 5 of the plots.

After the treatment has completed I would like to test if there was a change in CO2 output. I thought a paired t.test would be best for this but now I am overthinking it.

To run a paired t.test I think I would need to:

**A)** pick one random day before treatment and a random day after treatment

or

**B)** find the mean of all CO2 measures per plot before treatment and after the treatment.

In both instances, I would have a df = 4.

Do either of these options make sense? Or am I barking up the wrong tree with a t.test, possibly I just have too few samples.

Feel free to call me an idiot or link me to other places, but I've been scratching my head at this for too long and could use an outside perspective.

Comment: Repeated measures usually indicate the need for a mixed effects model. In this case I can imagine grouping observations by plot as a random effect and then treatment as a fixed effect. I'm not sure if/how time should be addressed though - do you expect a general increase in CO2 over time (before treatment)? [This book](https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/introduction.html) covers mixed effect models in R

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I think there might be issues with only half of your plots getting treated - someone else might be able to comment on this and how time should be modeled

Comment: Much potentially relevant information is missing from the problem description. For examples: Can the CO2 output be affected by external factors like the weather? How similar/dissimilar are the plots? Are they located close to each other?

Comment: Sounds like a BACI experiment. I think GLMMs are commonly used for this.

Comment: I should have mentioned the plots are near identical and the effects of weather will be the same on each plot. I'll take a look at GLMMs for sure.